# Espresso can't click an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-testing, android-espresso

my espresso instrumentation test can't click an ImageView:

> Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.example.test:id/btnNext'.
>
> Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.
>
> Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.InjectEventSecurityException: java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

But what is strange that just three lines before it is able to click another ImageView looking quite similar to me. **And using the app as human works as well**.

Here is my minimal non-working example, do you see the error?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class TestTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> _activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<TestActivity>(
            TestActivity.class);
    @Test
    public void testClicking() {
        onView(withId(R.id.btnPrevious)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.btnNext)).check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnNext)).check(matches(isClickable()));
        onView(withId(R.id.btnNext)).perform(click()); // This line throws an exception
    }
}
```

The activity to test:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
    }
}
```

And the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/lytFooter">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_arrow_shadow"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
            android:focusable="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/look_around"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            style="@style/CameraText" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/prgVideoMode"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:max="100" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_arrow_shadow"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/lightbutton_selector"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The full stracktrace is 80 lines long so I posted it here if you are interested: http://pastebin.com/RWa91G63

Comment: provide your onCLickListener method... As I understand after clicking view, you go to another app like Googles Photos, right?

Comment: @piotrek: actually this is the whole code. There is no onClick set (and even if I do and just add a simple Log.v() ), it is not executed.

Comment: And please notice that the click on btnPrevious works - no listener there as well.

Comment: i don't understand why you use ImageViews instead of ImageButtons and why you're performing click() action when there's no listener. So what doeas this nextBtn do?

Comment: This is the minimal-non-working example I compiled from my otherwise functional (and much larger) application. To make sure I did not forget anything, I moved them to an extra activity&test and watched them fail :-)